# Why update button is not showing up in table design tab in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a database in c#. But when I create a table, dont see "Update" button top left in table design tab to save it in my database.

This is a screenshot of my problem. (should be an update button in red area):

http://uupload.ir/files/e9ux_mine.png

Now how can I save tables?

Comment: did you try CTRL+S

Comment: Yes, but tables not saving in that way. I saw a video in youtube and i searched a lot about it.there should be a update btn and after update, i can refresh the database  and table will be added to database then i can save database.